# How to formating url conditionally in `$stateProvider` angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My `$stateProvider` provides:

```
$stateProvider.state('main.result', {
            'url': '/result'
                    + '/student/:studentId'
                    + '/school/:schoolId'
                    + '/display',
            'templateUrl':'/results/display.html',
            'controller': 'ExamDisplayController'
        });
```

In above url I passed Two id's
One is: studentId AND
Another One is: schoolId
here I want to format url conditionally on above two mention id's.
**EXPECTED**

If

`studentId !== null` AND `schoolId === null`

then url should be **`/result/student/:studentId/display`**

else if

`studentId === null` AND `schoolId !== null`

then url should be **`/result/school/:schoolId/display`**.

Comment: You should create a nested view for each one of the possibilities

Comment: how to create nested view ? and can i add condition in my url

Comment: Read this [guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views), I think it meight help

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator and based on it you can form url.

Try below code.

```
url = '/result' + (studentId !== null AND schoolId === null) ? '/student/:studentId' : '' 
                    + (studentId === null AND schoolId !== null) ? '/school/:schoolId' : ''
                    + '/display',
            'templateUrl':'/results/display.html',
            'controller': 'ExamDisplayController'

$stateProvider.state('main.result', {
            'url': url 
        });
```

Comment: How we compare studentId and if I want to pass studentId in that condition then how it will get studentId ? I mean How I will get studentId and schoolId in my `url`

Comment: I didn't get your question.

Comment: How I will get studentId and schoolId in my url ? and how should i compare it in url